# How to fix random seed for CGAL Mesh Skeletonization processes for unittest

Tags: random, cgal

I write unit tests for functions that use CGAL Mesh Skeletonization processes. As this CGAL process is randomized, results differ at each execution.

This function uses: `CGAL::Mean_curvature_flow_skeletonization<Polyhedron>::contract_until_convergence` and `convert_to_skeleton`

https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_skeletonization/classCGAL_1_1Mean__curvature__flow__skeletonization.html

For my unit tests, I try to set the same seed to CGAL::Random object, but as this object is not used by skeletonizer processes, they still produced different result a each execution.

Is it possible to fix random generator for CGAL in order to always obtain the same output with the same input ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: To seed random generators in CGAL you can use [`CGAL::get_default_random()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Generator/group__PkgGeneratorsRef.html#gaba8e19d6085c19ae8afe10fa55ed96ba)`=CGAL::Random(seed)` but IIRC, there are other sources of non determinism in this package (iteration order or something like that).

Comment: Indeed, there are other sources of non determinism in this package. Fixing the random seed as you mention is not enough to reproduce Surface_mesh_skeletonization results. 
But for simple function like uniform_int (https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Generator/classCGAL_1_1Random.html#abd650eef0561afe44556ec0e5ac78f5c), it allows to obtain same result at each call.